# Поиск подстроки в строке?

Tags: javascript

Читал материалы на тему 'Поиск подстроки в строке', но ни в одном из них не объяснили следующее:

- **Зачем и когда нужно делать поиск подстроки в строке.**

Comment: Жуткий вопрос :)
Вот например вы наверняка пользуетесь поиском в интернете или в файлах. Самый типичный пример (хотя поиск в Интернете устроен не совсем так как поиск подстроки в JS)
Другой пример - иногда нужно узнать есть некий фрагмент в строке или нет, все равно при этой задаче выполняется поиск

Comment: Как я понимаю, там идет поиск по базам данных(MySQL, SQL) на языке бекендных языков(Node.js,  PHP и тп.)
Разве там используют поиск подстроки?

Comment: Именно поэтому я и написал что в Интернете (в поисковых системах) это устроено иначе. А вот когда вы ищете слово в простом текстовом редакторе - там происходит поиск подстроки

Comment: Вопрос по типу "когда нужно делать умножение" или "когда нужно сохранять данные в файл". Когда того требует задача, тогда и нужно.

Comment: @Эникейщик, Вы плохой учитель для новичков)))

Comment: @Cyrax где написано, что я учитель? 

Comment: А кто вы)? Человек, который не хочет просвещать кого-либо, он не станет писать в комментарии, он просто пройдет мимо.

Comment: На самом деле поиск подстроки как правило выполняется когда стоит одна из целей 1. Подсчет количества вхождений подстроки (нужно сначала найти, а потом подсчитать) (частный случай этой цели - определение есть-ли такой фрагмент). 2. Определение "места" (или мест) в котором находится искомый фрагмент (например чтобы заменить его на другой)

Comment: Cпасибо за разъяснения! Вхождение в строку, это когда идет поиск подстроки в строке? Поиск подстроки поможет ли найти, к примеру другие данные кроме строки(переменную и массивы и тп)

Comment: Переменная это не другие данные. Переменная - условно говоря это имя и зарезервированное место для хранения данных (или ссылки на них). Строка и массив - это типы данных. В строке вы не сможете найти массив. А вот в массиве найти некоторый элемент (или множество элементов но это более редкий случай и готовые функции не всегда есть в языке) - сможете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например при валидация формы, у меня был случай, нужно было проверить, введено ли имя, пробелы тоже строка, но за имя его трудно воспринимать, и чтобы на сервер не приходили сообщения с пробелами нужно их отыскать и убрать в случае если нет никаких других слов

Comment: Кажется я понял зачем вся эта кухня)))

Answer (score 0):

Яркий пример:
Пишешь простенький текстовый редактор. Поиск по слову в тексте, где текст - одна большая строка. С помощью поиска подстроки ты получишь количество и позицию.

Так же и валидация, как подметил Ilya Shvets